browse sparse git checkout
In a sparse git checkout, one does not see the folders (directories/trees) that haven't been added via git sparse-checkout add.
I can still "browse" these folders with git cat-file -p HEAD and following the tree hashes.
Is there any tool or trick to make this more comfortable?

I've created this alias in my git config which is already a good enough solution for me:
[alias]
    ls = ls-tree --format='%(objecttype) %(path)' HEAD

It's not nice that:

I need to put a slash at the end of a folder to see its content.
The output is not as compact as the output of ls.


git show can also show other objects, not only commits, using <commit>:<path> as the specification.
For example, git show @: will list the root tree contents of the HEAD commit, 1 line per file, while git show @:README.txt will show the contents of the specified file.
To browse the tree interactively, use tig and press t to open its 'tree' view.
